# How to calculate a heart?

Tags: graphing-functions

I really like this girl Jenny in my math class. She is smart and kind and sweet and really, ***REALLY*** hot. I want to get her to notice me by graphing a heart on my TI calculator but I don't know if there's a single mathematical equation that can draw this when it graphs the line.

Please help.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your calculator to parametric graphing mode ([this page](http://mtl.math.uiuc.edu/non-credit/basic84plus/ti84plus-tutorial/ti84-tutorial23.html) shows you how to do that, if you don't know), and enter this parametric equation:

$$x(t)=16\sin^3(t)$$
$$y(t)=13\cos(t)-5\cos(2t)-2\cos(3t)-\cos(4t).$$

In the window tab, set `tmin=0` and `tmax=2*pi`
Here is the result:

[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 + (5 y/4 - (Sqrt[Abs[x]])^2\leq1$, $-n<x<n\;\;and\;\;-n<y<n$